# Невозможно зайти на сайт через HTTPS прокси Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: python, сеть, proxy

Я не могу зайти на сайт через HTTPS прокси. Список прокси я взял здесь: https://hidemy.io/ru/proxy-list/?type=s#list

Выбрал первый прокси `95.56.254.139:3128`, в аддоне для Firefox `Foxy Proxy` указал title прокси, Type HTTPS, Hostname 95.56.254.139, Port 3128 и включил этот прокси. Но при попытке зайти на сайт я получил ошибку:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to 2ip.ru. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Почему эта ошибка возникла и через прокси невозможно зайти на сайт?

Почему в питоне при выполнении запроса через библиотеку requests через прокси запрос тоже не отправяется?

```
proxies = {
        'https': '95.56.254.139:3128'
    }

response = requests.post(url=url, headers = headers, data=data, proxies = proxies)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бесплатные прокси очень низкого качества, предлагаю мини тестер для проверки прокси.

```
import requests

proto = 'https://'                    #
url = proto+'2ip.ru'                  # Адрес сайта для проверки
timeout=30                            #
proxy_list = ['95.56.254.139:3128']   # адрес:порт прокси

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/'
                         '5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/'
                         '20091102 Firefox/'
                         '3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)'}
host, port = proxy_list[0].split(':')

proxy_dic = {
    "http": f'{host}:{port}',
    "https": f'{host}:{port}'
}

print('wait->')
print(url, proxy_dic)
try:
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dic, timeout=timeout)
    text_pg = res.text
    b = text_pg.find('<span>', text_pg.find('div class="ip"'))+5   #
    e = text_pg.find('</span>', text_pg.find('div class="ip"'))    #
    ad = text_pg[b:e]                                              # ip адрес, с сайта 2ip.ru
    print('Статус подключения', res.status_code, 'Адрес:', ad)

except Exception as e:
    print(f'{host} is not working: {e}')
```